# Access object in array which is a property of another object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

It's been a long time since I learned OOP and I'm new to JS, so things might look weird for more advanced users - sorry :)

```
function page(title) {
    this.subPages = [];
    this.title = title;
}
page.prototype.addToSubPages = function(subPage) {
    this.subPages.push(subPage);
}
page.prototype.getSubPages = function() {
    return this.subPages;
}
```

Now I create 2 objects:

```
startPage = new page("start");
somePage  = new page("foo");
```

...and try to add `somePage` into the array in `startPage`:

```
startPage.addToSubPages(somePage);
```

Now this doesn't seem to work, although it should be correct, if I'm not mistaken.

```
console.log(startPage.getSubPages());
```

This shows me that *something* is in the array, but the object appears to be empty. What am I doing wrong?
Also: How would I access a certain element in that array? Like this: `startPage.getSubPages()[0].getFoo();`?

Edit: Holy Mackerel, Batman! This is more like my actual code: http://jsfiddle.net/pZHKS/2/
You're all right, the code I posted actually works. As soon as inheritance comes into play, it doesn't work anymore. Why, though? It should work exactly like the code above, right?

Comment: What makes you think this is broken? It works for me? http://jsfiddle.net/pZHKS/, http://jsfiddle.net/pZHKS/1/

Comment: `console.log(startPage.subPages[0].title);` Also avoid useless code like `getX()` that's a Java anti-pattern.

Comment: @Raynos: I'm not sure it's an anti-pattern. Encapsulation is useful (and has been useful to me in the wild) in JavaScript as well.

Comment: @Matt If by useful you mean a waste of computation, then yes. see [The cost of privacy](http://blog.jcoglan.com/2012/01/19/the-cost-of-privacy/)

Comment: @Raynos: Next time I have to construct 1,000,000 instances of an object and need the 200ms performance increase, I'll think twice ;).

Comment: @Matt It's not so much the performance overhead as it is the memory penalty, not to mention the memory leak vulnerabilities. Although it really depends how much you care. It's also ugly and verbose o/

Comment: @Raynos The article linked refers to the complications that arise from improper understanding of javascript scope and creating anonymous closures as abstractions around private data all while not understanding the inner workings of frameworks you may be abstracting. The only reason I mention this is because I did not take away at all that there is a detrimental effect to using a getter/setter level of encapsulation on javascript objects.

Comment: @QuintinRobinson There is no point in Getter/Setter if you have public properties. I would assume you only use Getters and Setters if your emulating "privacy". That's what encapsulation is about. In this example getX is just silly because it's a property already.

Comment: @Raynos I should have made clear that I am not arguing for or against getter/setters around your object fields, whether to use them or not is not a cookie cutter decision rather one that should be thought about during the design of the solution in question. I just merely wanted to state my interpretation of the linked article as it relates to the creation and definition of javascript objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function page(title) {
    this.title = title;
}

function subPage() {
    this.contentPages = [];
}
subPage.prototype = new page;
```

There are two problems.

1. your not calling `page` in `subPage`.
2. your using `Child.prototype = new Parent;` that's wrong, use `Object.create` instead

So the fixed code would be.

```
function page(title) {
    this.title = title;
}

function subPage(title) {
    page.call(this, title);
    this.contentPages = [];
}
subPage.prototype = Object.create(page.prototype);
```

Comment: ES5-shim should be used for oldIE support. Or some other kind of Object.create shim